# Getting links to all music releases on Qobuz

Tags: parsing

Good day to all.

There is a streaming service known as Qobuz.
When you try to share a music release you get a link: https://open.qobuz.com/album/d7rchuzba48lc

Only the ID changes at the end. My goal is to get a complete list of links to all existing releases that are in the service, and in the future to get new ones as they appear. How would this be done and is it generally possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've read some articles on parsing, but the problem is that there's actually nothing on the page *open.qobuz.com/album/*, it's just a *folder* that contains pages of millions of releases. Is there any way to pull this off?

Comment: "Nothing on the page"? There is HTML, therefore it can be parsed. Please share what you've tried since Stackoverflow is not a site to have people do it for you. Refer [help]

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Short answer: Those IDs are stored in a database and are not accessible to you. If they wanted you to get them they'd provide an API endpoint which returns the listing. Parsing a web page isn't even close to the right way.